# Two factor authentication in Azure PowerShell functions

Tags: powershell, azure-functions

I'm trying to find a way to connect to a Microsoft account with 2FA enabled using an Azure function. However, `Get-Credential` doesn't seem to do the trick.

Is there maybe a way to obtain a link to authenticate or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

When you have 2FA activated, you can't use normal credentials when connecting. You can specify the username though.

Use *Connect-AzureAd -AccountId*  and a window will show for you to enter password.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, this won't work as Azure functions are running headless.